# Calculate BACKLOG_M_1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the BLACKLOG_M value corresponding to the Snapdate of the first of the month. It becomes a constant value repeated for each line of the month

As it is explained in the picture:

[image]

```
SELECT     T1.SNAP, T1.PERI, T1.ANNEE, T1.MOIS, T1.[BCKL], T2.[BCKL] AS BCK2,[NBR1]
      ,[NBR2]
FROM         stg.FACTSALES AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (SELECT     YEAR(SNAP) AS ANNEE, MONTH(SNAP) AS MOIS, [BCKL]
                            FROM          stg.FACTSALES
                            WHERE      (DAY(SNAP) = 1)) AS T2 ON T2.ANNEE = T1.ANNEE AND T2.MOIS = T1.MOIS
```

The script returns the correct values, but is there any another best idea or improvement?

Comment: Your code is working, you may want to visit codereview.stackexchange.com for improvements. Also, you need to provide DDL for the tables including indexes and the query plan for anyone to make meaningful contributions to this code.

Comment: Does the table **ALWAYS** have a row the first day (`1`) of the month?

Comment: @TheImpaler yes the table has always a row the first day (1) of the month

Comment: What is the logic for the value on the first day?  Your query would give it the same value as the other days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to copy the value from the first day of the month through the rest of the month.  That should be possible.

```
select fs.*,
       (case when day(snapdate) = 1
             then max(case when day_snapdate() = 1 then backlog_m end) over (partition by year_month)
        end) as backlog_m_1
from stg.FACTSALES fs;
```

This assigns the value on the first day as well.  It is not clear what you want for that value.

Comment: i GET ERROR Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

Comment: @NewbieSQL . . . The outer `max()` was a mistake.